# returning values from python functions

Tags: python

First off apologies if this has been asked before. I'm a newcomer to coding, as you'll soon see.

I've simplified what I'm trying to achieve below.

In essence, I would like to pass two variables into either functions below (fun1 or fun2 could be initiated first). Once either val1 or val2 has reached 0, I would like to return the alternate value. Obviously in the example below, val2 will always reach 0 and fun1 will be initiated first.

I was wondering if there's a way to return the value to blah? I understand that the below example will be creating some ridiculous loop between the two functions, but I've no idea how to accomplish what I'm after, without extensive if statements and a singular function.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    def fun1(val1, val2):
        val2 -= 1
        if val2 > 0:
            print "val2: ", val2
            fun2(val1, val2)
        else:
            print "val2 ended"
            return val1

    def fun2(val1, val2):
        val1 -= 1
        if val1 > 0:
            print "val1: ", val1
            fun1(val1, val2)
        else:
            print "val1 ended"
            return val2

    blah = fun1(10,8)
    print blah
```

Comment: Do you mean return the result of fun2 on line 5?

Comment: Aye, it seems that's where I was going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, you can do this recursively, what this does is that it will return the value that is returned by the function is called, so on and so forth until it decrements to -1, and then it will return the final number to blah

```
def fun1(val1, val2):
    val2 -= 1
    if val2 > 0:
        print "val2: ", val2
        return fun2(val1, val2)
    else:
        print "val2 ended"
        return val1

def fun2(val1, val2):
    val1 -= 1
    if val1 > 0:
        print "val1: ", val1
        return fun1(val1, val2)
    else:
        print "val1 ended"
        return val2

blah = fun1(10,8)
print blah
```

This will store the result in `blah`

Comment: @user1887639 no problem, remember to accept an answer :) let me know if you need me to explain more

Answer (score 2):

Quite easily! When you do your recursive calls (calling the other functions), just return their value instead of ignoring it. Like this:

```
def fun1(val1, val2):
    val2 -= 1
    if val2 > 0:
        return fun2(val1, val2) # RETURN the result!
    else:
        print "val2 ended"
        return val1

def fun2(val1, val2):
    val1 -= 1
    if val1 > 0:
        return fun1(val1, val2) # RETURN the result!
    else:
        print "val1 ended"
        return val2
```

This way, no matter which code path you take, you always return a result at each step to the next level above.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you `return fun2(...)` and `return fun1(...)`. Without the `return`s, Python functions return `None` by default.

```
def fun1(val1, val2):
    val2 -= 1
    if val2 > 0:
        print "val2: ", val2
        return fun2(val1, val2)
    else:
        print "val2 ended"
        return val1

def fun2(val1, val2):
    val1 -= 1
    if val1 > 0:
        print "val1: ", val1
        return fun1(val1, val2)
    else:
        print "val1 ended"
        return val2

blah = fun1(10,8)
print blah
```